# Guest has not initialized the display (yet)

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu, x86, emulation

I'm trying to emulate a raspberry pi using an x86 system and qemu.
I'm trying to launch it like:

```
$ qemu-system-arm -kernel ~/Downloads/kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda ~/Downloads/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img -show-cursor`
```

The `kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster` I got from [here](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel) while the `raspbian-buster-lite.img` is the regular image from [raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) (I also tried the above command but with `2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.img` - which produces the same result)

All I get when I launch this command, is a black `qemu` window that reads "Guest has not initialized the display (yet)" and I'm wondering why this is the case...?

Comment: I also gets this error but only when specifying memory size of 2200MB-2500MB (running Debian on a server), so it's not likely you have the same issue, but who know! But you could try to change the memory size if you still have the issue.